# Автоматическое создание пространства имен в новосозданный файлах

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Допустим, я создаю некую структуру в проекте, создавая директорию.

Помещая в эту директорию файл класса, `Resharper` автоматически генерит для этого класса пространство имен с этим именем.

Это очень удобно, однако, как быть если я хочу использовать некоторую директорию просто, как группировку файлов кода и что бы имя этой директории не шло в пространство имен?

Можно ли как-то исключить определенные директории из этого правила?

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Выделяем нужную папку в Solution Explorer, нажимаем F4 (или в контекстном меню для папки выбираем Properties), в появившемся окошке Properties находим `ReSharper | Namespace provider` и меняем его значение на False.